# Puzzles with solution related to Puzzling itself

Tags: discussion

I recently solved a [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122168/could-you-find-the-way-in-this-maze-of-rebuses) with solution very closely related to Puzzling:

> the solution is `PuzzlingStackExchange`!

I recall seeing puzzles (a long time ago) whose solutions refer to Puzzling itself or the act of solving puzzles. But I for the life of me cannot find them, because spoiler blocks cannot be searched.

Does anyone know any others? I think it'll be fun if there's a list of them.

For example, here is one [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86971/a-story-puzzle-for-you) where

> both the puzzle and the solution are related to PuzzlingStackExchange.

(By the way, first meta post here, please let me know if this kind of post is not allowed)

Comment: It's a nice idea to gather a list as you suggest, but there's soooo many puzzles like this, I don't think we can ever complete the list ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor really? It took me days to find that other one.

Comment: My point exactly: there's so many of them but it'll take ages to track them down, as search isn't very helpful here. Although speaking of search, probably [most of these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=stack+exchange+is%3Aq) would make a start.

Comment: To attempt to bring the sheer total down, I would suggest that such a list should only comprise puzzles that have reached a certain upvote threshold, e.g. +25, which is the threshold for a silver 'Good Question' badge. This may introduce a bias towards older questions or those that hit HNQs, but we would need to do *something* to filter what would otherwise quickly become a too-long list of quite poor-quality puzzles, albeit from well-meaning users...